# How was iOS UI AutoLayout Engine implemented?

Tags: xcode, algorithm, autolayout, layout-engine

I need to implement something like iOS AutoLayout engine in my project. The problem is not the same, but I hope that the implementation idea will be helpful for me.

I'll be grateful for any help.